# Calling Method w/ Argument on Main Thread from Secondary Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Like the title suggest I have an android project with a MainActivity class that has a TextView that I want to set the text of after receiving a message. I also have a class that runs a ServerSocket on a separate thread that receives the string message I want to display.

Part of my MainActivity looks like this,

```
private Handler UIHandler = new Handler();
private RemoteControlServer remoteConnection;
public static final int controlPort = 9090;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener
{
    ...

    remoteConnection = new RemoteControlServer(controlPort, UIHandler);

    ...

    private class RemoteControlServer extends RemoteControl
    {
        RemoteControlServer(int port, Handler ui)
        {
            super(port, ui);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(String[] msg)
        {
            //updates messages textview
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotify(String[] msg)
        {
            //updates notification textview
        }
    }
}
```

The RemoteControlServer implementation of code that calls the onReceive(String[] msg) and also handles receiving messages on the different thread looks like this,

```
...

public abstract void onReceive(String[] msg);
public abstract void onNotify(String[] msg);

...

controlListener = new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    boolean running = true;
    public void run()
    {
        String line = null;
        while(running)
        {
            try
            {
                //Handle incoming messages

                ...

                onReceive(messages);    
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                UIHandler.post(new Runnable()
                {
                    public void run()
                    {
                        onNotify("Wifi Receive Failed " + e.toString() + "\n");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});

...
```

I'm getting the error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." when onReceive() is called and throws the exception and calls onNotify() with the exception description. Why does the onNotify() work but the otherone does not? How can I correctly call the listener to the the TextView and update its text? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class RemoteControlServer extends RemoteControl
{

    ...

    public class BridgeThread implements Runnable
    {
        String[] msgArray = null;
        public BridgeThread(String[] msg)
        {
            msgArray = msg;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {   
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    TextView zValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
                    zValue.setText(msgArray[0]);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(String[] msg)
    {
        BridgeThread bridgeTest = new BridgeThread(msg);
        bridgeTest.run();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Would this replace my current new Thread() code? Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't this run my ServerSocket on the UI thread (which I don't want to do)?

Comment: when u receive a String that you want to display in TextView ... just copy that code and call setText with that string on textview  (in my code above it is //set your text) ... the thing is that you will call UI thread (UI thread can work with user interface, and thats what you want) from another thread that you have implemented for receiving messages ... makes that any sence for you ? :) i am not that good in EN :/

Comment: Alright thanks Matej for the suggestion I'll give it a try in a few

Comment: How would I pass the "String[] msg" object in the code you provide so I can set the text to be the msg? The run() method isn't suppose to have any argument.

Comment: PS. your suggestion does indeed work for setting the text, I just need to set the text to be the something that I receive so it won't work unless I can pass an argument into that run() method

Comment: i dont really know how to have implemented it ... but you can for example generate getter and setter for String[] msg and call getMsg in UI thread ...